# Improving CNN Regression model: make more fit each data point

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, regression

I want to predict a force plate data using smart insole data. I'm trying to implement a CNN model for Regression prediction. The following is data from the force plate and smart insole

> Force Plate Data: [ 4.06604 -63.9543]
>
> Force Plate Data Shape : (2050,2)
>
> SmartInsole Data: [  0.   0.   0.  13.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
> 15.  92.  60.   0.
> 36.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  62.  80.  58.  37.   0.   0.   0.
> 0.  40.  83.  72.  32.  22.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  98. 108.
> 74.  56.  30.  17.   0.   0.  44. 121. 127.  83.   0.   0.   0.   0.
> 0.   3.  83.  64.  63.  63.  77.  70.  43.  55. 115. 138. 144. 137.
> 0.   0.   0.   0.  66. 107. 127. 146. 150.  52.   0.   0.   0. 129.
> 133.  18.   0.   0.   0.]
>
> SmartInsole Data Shape : (2050,89)

then I did transforming data from value to picture. here the input shape will be 3D array. Smartinsole data that has been changed to image as below:

> SmartInsole Data After Transforming to Picture :

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  46.  35.   1.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   2.  48. 106. 143.  72.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  82.  75. 135. 147. 152.  19.]
 [  0.   0.   0. 100.  89. 130. 140. 148. 131.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  19.  45.  69. 121. 130. 132.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  94. 113.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  66.  79.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  38.  84.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  26.  59.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   2.  51.  68.  65.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  14.  68.  76.  38.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  65.  80. 101.  46.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  52.  64.  90.  62.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  14.  33.  33.   6.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

> SmartInsole Shape After Transforming to Picture : (2050,19,9)

Below is a picture of the results of the smart insole data transformation
[image]

Below is my trial code. This code runs without error.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
%matplotlib inline

## Load Data
Insole = pd.read_csv('1119_Rwalk40s1_list.txt', header=None, low_memory=False)
SIData =  np.asarray(Insole)

df = pd.read_csv('1119_Rwalk40s1.csv', low_memory=False)
columns = ['Fx','Fz']
selected_df = df[columns]
FCDatas = selected_df[:2050]
## End Load Data

# Transform Data to Picture
SIData2D = SIData

def list2matR(SIData2D):

  t=np.zeros((19,6))
  rows = 18
  cols = 5
    
  col4=[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2]
  col4idx=0
  col5=[8,7,6,5,4,3]
  col5idx=0

  for idx, val in enumerate(SIData2D):
        
    if idx <=56:
      t[rows-(idx%19)][math.floor(idx/19)]=val
    elif idx<=73:
      if (idx%19!=0 or idx%19!=18):
#                 print(rows-(idx%19)-1)
#                 print(math.floor(idx/19))
        t[rows-(idx%19)-1][math.floor(idx/19)]=val
    elif (idx<=82 and col4idx<9):
#             print(val)
      t[col4[col4idx]][4]=val
      col4idx+=1
    elif col5idx<6:
#             print(val)
      t[col5[col5idx]][5]=val
      col5idx+=1

  return t

def lplusr(R):
  z = np.zeros((19,3))

  return np.concatenate((z,R), axis=1)

def formPic(SIData2D):
  return lplusr(list2matR(SIData2D))

# data preprocess to train
r1 = SIData
train = []

for i in range(0,len(r1)):
  train.append(formPic(r1[i]))

SmartInsole = np.array(train[:2050])
FCData = np.array(FCDatas)

xX = SmartInsole
yY = FCData

scalers = {}
for i in range(xX.shape[1]):
    scalers[i] = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    xX[:, i, :] = scalers[i].fit_transform(xX[:, i, :]) 

scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_y.fit(yY)
yscale = scaler_y.transform(yY)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xX, yscale, test_size=0.25, random_state=2)

img_width, img_height, img_num_channels = 19, 9, 1

input_shape = (img_width, img_height, img_num_channels)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='huber', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=50, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=2,shuffle=True)

ypred = model.predict(xX)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
# plt.show()
plt.savefig('Loss Result.png')

print('MSE: ',mean_squared_error(yscale, ypred))
print('RMSE: ',math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(yscale, ypred)))
print('Coefficient of determination (r2 Score): ', r2_score(yscale, ypred))

ypred = scaler_y.inverse_transform(ypred) 
yscale = scaler_y.inverse_transform(yscale) 

x=[]
colors=['red','green','brown','teal','gray','black','maroon','orange','purple']
colors2=['green','red','orange','black','maroon','teal','blue','gray','brown']
for i in range(0,2050):
    x.append(i)
for i in range(0,2):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    # plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,yscale[0:2050,i], color=colors[i])
    plt.plot(x,ypred[0:2050,i], markerfacecolor='none',color=colors2[i])
    plt.title('Result for ResNet Regression')
    plt.ylabel('Y value')
    plt.xlabel('Instance')
    plt.legend(['Real value', 'Predicted Value'], loc='upper right')
    plt.savefig('Regression Result.png'[i])
    plt.show()
```

The Prediction results
[image]
[image]

my question is how to improve the model to be able to predict the data more fit?